# Should I try to prove $E(|X|)=\int^{\infty}_0P(|X|>t) dt$ or $E(|X|)=\int^{\infty}_0P(|X|\geq t) dt$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm trying to prove that $E(|X|)=\int^{\infty}_0P(|X|>t) dt$.

However, when I use fubini: I have $$\int_{[0,\infty)}\int_{|X|>t}$$ and transform it to $$\int_{0<|X|} \int_{[0,|X|)}$$. There's the slight problem that the dist of $|X|$ may have mass at $0$...

I would like to have $$\int_{0\leq |X|} \int_{[0,|X|)} 1 dt dP=\int_{\Omega} |X| dP = E(|X|)$$

So, should I try to prove $E(|X|)=\int^{\infty}_0P(|X|>t) dt$ or $E(|X|)=\int^{\infty}_0P(|X|\geq t) dt$?

Comment: Even if $P(|X|=0)>0$, the contribution of that single point to the integral will still be zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are true. That's because $x$ is both equal to $\int_0^\infty \mathbb 1_{t \leq x}dt$ and $\int_0^\infty \mathbb 1_{t < x}dt$.